# Shortcut for creating character array

Tags: c#, array-initialization

Since I like to `Split()` `string`s, I usually use

```
new char[] { ';' }
```

or something like that for a parameter for `Split()`.

Is there any shortcut for creating a character array with one element at compile time?  Not that I mind typing, but...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Especially for multiple elements, the following shortcut is nice:

```
";".ToCharArray()
```

You can use this with multiple chars:

```
";,\t".ToCharArray()
```

Comment: Great shortcut. I will never forget this one :)

Answer (score 22):

In C# 3, you can use an implicitly-typed array:

```
new[] { ';' }
```

If you're not passing a `StringSplitOptions`, you can simply take advantage of the `params` parameter:

```
.Split(',')
```